# How to align two LinearLayouts?

Tags: android

I want to make an base calculator app, so i started to make buttons for each number and operation. To keep them align i used an RelativeLayout but under it i have five LinearLayouts, each LinerarLayout represents a row of buttons.

My problem is the following, after i use `layout_alignBottom` to the first row in order to keep it at the bottom of the screen, i tried to use `layout_above` to align the second row above the first but it seems that i can't do that because i get an `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/firstRow').` error, in fact i get this error for all the alignments attributes.

Here is a part of my xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondRow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/firstRow">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:text="1" />

        <!-- more buttons -->


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstRow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bP"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="." />

     <!-- more buttons -->

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i align the LinearLayouts in an way that the first row is at the bottom of the screen and the others are one above each others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML is rendered from top to bottom, therefore, if you want to add a reference to an element that is after the one you are adding the reference to, you need to call `@+id` instead of `@id`. In your case you should write this:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/firstRow"
```

This happens because at the time you are running the code from your first `LinearLayout`, Android doesn't have any element registered with the id "firstRow" since it wasn't compiled yet, so you need to add the `+` meaning that if it find any reference later on, it will be set, if not, it just aligns the view without the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this in a more complicated way than is necessary.

Just wrap them in a vertical oriented linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:text="1" />

    <!-- more buttons -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:text="3" />

    <!-- more buttons -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Your rows in order from top to bottom -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:layout_toStartOf` and `android:layout_toEndOf`